# Is ubuntu installation good for me?

Tags: system-installation

I have windows as a operating system, I have 2 GB RAM, and intel pentium processor. Currently my PC is very slow. If I install ubuntu on my pc instead of windows, will my problem be solved? If yes, then which version of Ubuntu should I install?
And will it effect my files, softwares etc if I move from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: That depends on your definition of "good" :-)

Comment: Download and iso and put it on Flash and try the live version, if it works for you well backup your data and install.
P.S: Be sure to check the 86x and 64x versions before downloading (depending on your browser).

Answer (score 1):

For your system specs, I'd suggest trying Lubuntu or Xubuntu on a Live media (USB stick or DVD).  Do note that any flavor of Ubuntu will be better/faster when installed on a local HDD or SSD than it will from a USB or optical drive, as those media are very slow and, by default, your customizations won't stick.

If your old Pentium machine is running Windows XP, you'll find Lubuntu to give similar performance, in general; if it's a newer version of Windows (Vista, 7, 8, or 10) most if not all flavors of Ubuntu will work "better".

FWIW, I run Kubuntu on a Dell Latitude D520, with 1.8 GHz dual core (mobile version of Core2Duo) and 2 GB RAM; it's very acceptable for word processing and basic browsing, but a little laggy if I try to play a game with any significant graphics load.  Kubuntu is one of the "heaviest" flavors of Ubuntu, so it seems to me that, in general, one of the lighter flavors should work well enough with your specs.

Answer (score 0):

As a widows user you might like the elementary os, current version is based on ubuntu 16.04. I am running it on a netbook from 2010 and in my opinion the gui is faster than the default unity installation. To the second part of your question the answer is yes, it will affect your files, since modern linux distributions are using different file system apart from windows ntfs. Download the iso on elementary.io home page, if you want to support the project, fill the amount you want to contribute ( might be 0 if you do not wish to contribute) and download the iso. Then use unetbootin program or iso burner to make bootable usb or dvd. Try the live CD before install, especially whether your hardware is compatible - wifi, bluetooth, graphics, etc.

Get an external usb HD and copy your files there.

Install the operating system and copy your files from usb HD back to your new operating system.